# JsonProperty with property names containing underscores returns null

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc

I'm using MVC C#4, .NET 4.5.2. I'm trying to send a Postman request to my route, but the json properties with underscore names makes the request property in the method return null.

Json request

```
{
    {
        "channel": "/api/v5",
        "action": "added",
        "resource_id": "d5276373-a975-43d5-a361-6947b20bb666",
        "app_user_auth": {
            "access_token": "78505b15-3c46-4287-8658-f52238b94724",
            "token_type": "Bearer",
            "expires_in": 300,
            "user_id": "7e575bd7-3a4a-46bd-b449-c99d919de8534",
            "organization_id": "a5f832fa-6226-4a6f-a7ff-b75758fd57ed"
        }
    }
}
```

Request.cs

```
[JsonObject]
public class Request
{
    [JsonProperty("channel")]
    public string Channel { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("action")]
    public string Action { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("resource_id")]
    public string ResourceId { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("app_user_auth")]
    public AppUserAuth AppUserAuth { get; set; }
}

[JsonObject]
public class AppUserAuth
{
    [JsonProperty("access_token")]
    public string AccessToken { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("token_type")]
    public string TokenType { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("expires_in")]
    public int ExpiresIn { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("user_id")]
    public string UserId { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("organization_id")]
    public string OrganizationId { get; set; }
}
```

Controller.cs

```
[System.Web.Mvc.Route("webhook")]
[System.Web.Http.HttpPost]
public void WebHook([FromBody]Request request)
{
}
```

But here the request is

```
Action: "added"
AppUserAuth: null
Channel: "/api/v5"
ResourceId: null
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: I see additional bracket in `JSON` file. can you try after removing the additional bracket

Comment: @KrishnaMuppalla That is not the problem, I've cropped the json to fit the SO post. This request works if I don't try to convert the json to C# classes.

Comment: The JSON and C# classes are looking good. I dont see any problems here.

Comment: The `JsonProperty` attribute is from the Newtonsoft.Json package right? Is this supported by MVC's `FromBody` attribute?

Comment: [tag:asp.net-mvc-4]  still uses `JavaScriptSerializer`, see [MVC4 JSON.Net oob](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13859321/3744182) and [Setting the default JSON serializer in ASP.NET MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14591750/3744182).  MVC 6 is when Json.NET starts getting used.  (And in asp.net-core-3.0 the new `System.Text.Json` is used by default.)

Comment: Can you confirm you're using [tag:asp.net-mvc-4]?  The wording of your question is a little ambiguous.  If you are using MVC4 you'll probably need to use a DTO whose property names are exactly the same as the JSON property names, as `JavaScriptSerializer` does not support renaming of properties via attributes.

Comment: Hi! It seems like I have Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc 5.2.3. There seems to be many options out there for this question.

Comment: This worked for me use SnakeCaseNamingStrategy
https://stackoverflow.com/a/65019362/1831734

Answer (score 0):

Use Newtonsoft.Json as default.
In .NET Core include the NuGet package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson and add

```
services.AddControllers().AddNewtonsoftJson();
```

to `ConfigureServices` in Startup.cs.

*Choose the version of the package which works with your .NET version*